# Finding position of first letter in subtring in list of strings (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, find, substring

I have a list of strings, and I'm trying to find the position of the first letter of the substring I am searching for in the list of strings. I'm using the find() method to do this, however when I try to print the position of the first letter Python returns the correct position but then throws a -1 after it, like it couldn't find the substring, but only after it could find it. I want to know how to return the position of the first letter of he substring without returning a -1 after the correct value.

Here is my code:

```
mylist = ["blasdactiverehu", "sdfsfgiuyremdn"]

word = "active"

if any(word in x for x in mylist) == True:
    for x in mylist:
        position = x.find(word)
        print(position)
```

The output is:

```
5
-1
```

I expected the output to just be:

```
5
```

I think it may be related to the fact the loop is searching for the substring for every string in the list and after it's found the position it still searches for more but of course returns an error as there is only one occurrence of the substring "active", however I'm not sure how to stop searching after successfully finding one substring. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please let me know if you can mark my answer as the right one, or if further assistance is needed, so other people with the same problem can rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your code will not work as you want it to, since  given that any of the words contain the substring, it will do the check for each and every one of them.
A good way to avoid that is using a generator. More specifically, **next()**

```
default_val = '-1'
position = next((x.find(word) for x in mylist if word in x), default_val)
print(position)
```

It will simply give you the position of the substring "word" for the first string "x" that will qualify for the condition `if word in x`, in the list 'mylist'.

By the way, no need to check for == True when using any(), it already returns True/False, so you can simply do `if any(): ...`